# Gap appears in drop-down navigation only when page is scrolled

Tags: html, css, nav

I recently built my first website (with much trial and error) and was quite pleased until I noticed that when you scroll down the page a little it creates a gap in the navigation so you can't click on the dropdowns. I'm going crazy trying to fix it. Can anyone please help? The site is at: http://lamplighters.org/education/smw.html

Comment: Please post the relevant code here (edit your question and include the code).

Answer (score 0):

it appears to be an position issue that is set witht the element on the css. It would help to see your html and css code.

Comment: Agreed: `#nav li ul {
position: fixed;`

Comment: @user2566180 you may want to change it to absolute.

Comment: Thank you both! That sort of worked but added a scroll bar to the header and hid the text when *not* scrolled. I will play with this for a while, I don't remember seeing that before.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you that it has to do with the fact you used `position: fixed`. You have a series of other problems with your CSS as well.

Answer (score 0):

I inspeceted the page and found a lot of things that didn't come together well for the navigation. Good housekeeping is not in order.

```
#nav, #nav ul {/*By doing this you are setting these attributes to both the nav div and the nav ul*/
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
list-style: none;
line-height: 1;
text-align: center;
}
#nav, #nav ul {/*By doing this you are setting these attributes to both the nav div and the nav ul. This is redundant and should be consolodated into a single #nav, #nav ul, if you are going to use these assigned attributes. */
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
}
ul {/*By doing this you are only targeting any ul on the page*/
list-style: none outside;
}
ul, ol {/*By doing this are targeting both ordered lists and unordered lists to have these attributes*/
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
ol, ul {/*By doing this are targeting both ordered lists and unordered lists to have these attributes*/
list-style: none;
}

#nav li {
float: left;
width: 137px;
text-transform: capitalize;
display: inherit;
position: relative;
}
li {
line-height: 18px;
margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

You may want to wipe your nav css clean and start from scratch. 
I pulled a css file and put it below. hope this helps. Good luck with your sytle sheets in the future.

```
#menu{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 50px 0 0 0;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#menu li{
    float: left;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
    position: relative;
}

#menu a{
    float: left;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 0 60px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
/*Text Color for the anchors*/
#menu li:hover > a{
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

*html #menu li a:hover{ /* IE6 */
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#menu li:hover > ul{
    display: block;
}



/* Sub-menu */

#menu ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 35px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99999;
}

#menu ul li{
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
}

#menu ul a{    
    padding: 10px;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 1;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: none;
    text-transform: none;
}

*html #menu ul a{ /* IE6 */   
    height: 10px;
    width: 150px;
}

*:first-child+html #menu ul a{ /* IE7 */
    height: 10px;
    width: 150px;
}

#menu ul a:hover{
    /*add a background position*/
    background-position: left top;
}

#menu ul li:first-child a{
}

#menu ul li:first-child a:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
    top: -8px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}

#menu ul li:first-child a:hover:after{
    /*add color scheme*/
}

#menu ul li:last-child a{
}



/* Clear floated elements */
#menu:after{
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}

* html #menu             { zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
*:first-child+html #menu { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */
```